# How to use a function signature which takes a private struct as argument

Tags: go, closures, signature

I'm interested in using the [`github.com/mosen/vpp`](https://github.com/mosen/vpp) library to interact with Apple's Volume Purchase Program (VPP) APIs. To start off I was looking at the `GetLicenses()` method (cf. https://github.com/mosen/vpp/blob/eb451c2d433e9548c025737cf8b4fcef5c1f5b80/licenses.go#L58-L83), which reads

```
type getLicensesRequestOpts struct {
    AssignedOnly bool         `json:"assignedOnly,omitempty"`
    AdamID       int          `json:"adamId,omitempty"`
    PricingParam PricingParam `json:"pricingParam,omitempty"`
}

// GetLicensesOption describes the signature of the closure returned by a function adding an argument to GetLicenses
type GetLicensesOption func(*getLicensesRequestOpts) error

// GetLicenses retrieves a list of available VPP licenses. The result can optionally be filtered by the application id
// and/or its assigned status.
func (s *licensesService) GetLicenses(batch *BatchRequest, opts ...GetLicensesOption) ([]VPPLicense, error) {
    requestOpts := &getLicensesRequestOpts{}
    for _, option := range opts {
        if err := option(requestOpts); err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
    }
    var request *getVPPLicensesSrvRequest = &getVPPLicensesSrvRequest{
        getLicensesRequestOpts: requestOpts,
        SToken:                 s.sToken,
        BatchRequest:           batch,
    }
    var response getVPPLicensesSrvResponse
    req, err := s.client.NewRequest("POST", s.client.Config.serviceConfig.GetLicensesSrvURL, request)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    err = s.client.Do(req, &response)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if response.Status == StatusErr {
        return nil, response.VPPError
    }
    return response.Licenses, nil
}
```

This exported function is not invoked anywhere in that project, so it seems that one should use it directly, but I'm not sure how given that `getLicensesRequestOpts` is private. I would like to define a `GetLicensesOption` like

```
func assignedOnlyOption(opts *vpp.getLicensesRequestOpts) error {
    opts.AssignedOnly = true
    return nil
}
```

and then invoke the method like

```
vpp.NewService("my sToken").GetLicenses(&vpp.BatchRequest{}, assignedOnlyOption)
```

However, I don't believe I can define such an option if `getLicensesRequestOpts` is private unless I add it to that library itself.

In short, I don't understand how users are supposed to make use of this method?

Comment: With this kind of design, I'd expect to see some predefined vars of type `getLicensesRequestOpts`, emulating an enumerated type.

Comment: The package does not provide way to set the option. Contact the package author for help or fork the package.

Comment: `Latest commit eb451c2 on Aug 28, 2016`

yeah you are probably going to fork this package